# How to Update Commerce Product Programatically

Tags: commerce

```
 $product_load = commerce_product_load(456);

 $product_load->uid = $GLOBALS['user']->uid; 

 $product_load->example[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = 123;

 commerce_product_save($product_load);
```

As I am doing this it is not updating commerce product and takes lot of time to load the page.

Comment: The syntax and methods are correct, you definitely have a field named `example` in there? It's not called `field_example`?

Comment: i am having example field in my DB but still it is not updating.when creating new product or manually added , it is updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have better luck using entity metadata wrappers' ->set() and ->save() functions.